# AngularJS unit testing a Directive which requires model (Using Jasmine)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, directive

I am new to Anuglar JS unit testing using jasmine, I have a directive that requires model. following is the code for the directive (it only append $ sign before provide number in a given model:

```
directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;

            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
                //return '$' + $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue);
                var num = $filter('currency')(ctrl.$modelValue);
                return num.split('.')[0];
            });

            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
                plainNumber = $filter('number')(plainNumber);
                var inputVal = plainNumber.indexOf('$') < 0 ? '$' + plainNumber : plainNumber;
                elem.val(inputVal);
                return plainNumber;
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

I have been looking into jamine I was able to test filters and controllers easily and also some of directives but this one reuiqres model so I am stuck at it any suggestions? highly grateful for your suggestions (in advance :) )

Best regards
Sajid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably write your test like this:

```
it('tests this directive', inject(function($rootScope, $compile){
  var scope = $rootScope.$new();
  scope.myModelValue = 'something';
  var html = '<input format ng-model="myModelValue"></input>'

  var element = $compile(html)(scope);
  // I can't remember, but I think you need to call a scope.$apply() here
  // element.val() will return formatted value from the $parsers
  // Then element.val('something else') && scope.$apply() should change myModelValue from $formatters
}));
```